# Why does induction procedure of Euler characteristic fail for non-convex polyhedra? What am I missing?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, education, polyhedra

Euler characteristic of convex polyhedra is always $V-E+F=2$.

Induction procedure reduces edges and vertices until we are down to one vertex whose $V-E+F=2$ and hence you are done.

The same induction procedure should also work for non-convex polyhedra and reduce to one vertex. So why does the induction procedure not work for non-convex polyhedra(giving $\neq 2$ values sometimes)?

Please use elementary language in your description (for example, a talk to freshmen).

Comment: Well, for some nonconvex polyhedra it is not <2.

Comment: Well, for some nonconvex polyhedra it is =2. What you want to ask is, why is thebEuler characteristic of nonconvex polyhedra not always 2.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez changed!

Comment: What happens with the induction procedure if the polyhedron is a cube with a hole drilled through it?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip COuld you please elaborate as an answer in elementary terms?

Answer (score 2):

The proof I know that $V-E+F=1$ for convex polyhedra starts by removing a face, then stereographically projecting the complement into the plane, to get a convex polygon in the plane subdivided into smaller polygons. Then one removes pairs of edges and vertices or edges and faces until you get down to a point.

The thing that fails in the nonconvex case is that after you remove a face, you can't necessarily project the rest into the plane. For example, if your polyhedron is shaped like a torus (so it has a hole in it), once you remove a face, the rest of the polyhedron can not be embedded in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is not just one induction proof of Euler's theorem. David Eppstein has gathered
20 distinct proofs [at this link](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/).

---

[image: DavidEppsteinFig]

---

Second, most of the induction proofs *do* work for nonconvex polyhedra (but see below).
The one illustrated above (mentioned by @GrumpParsnip; figure from Eppstein's website) does not because it
uses stereographic projection. But if you instead just imagine topologically stretching
out one face boundary to become the outer boundary in the plane (rather than geometrically projecting),
the same proof works.

Third, as @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez hints, there are nonconvex polyhedra for which
the Euler characteristic is not $2$ (and for which some of the 20 proofs mentioned
above do not work). Only those polyhedra homeomorphic (stretchable) to
a sphere have $=2$ as the right-hand-side. If the "polyhedron" has a hole (like a torus)
or a cavity, the right-hand-side is $\neq 2$.

Comment: what do you mean by " topologically stretching out one face boundary to become the outer boundary in the plane" as opposed to "geometrically projecting"?

Comment: @Turbo: Imagine the wireframe of the polyhedron is made of stretchable rubber tubes. Then you could stretch any face to be the outermost face in the planar layout.

Comment: _______
|  |  |
|_/ \_|
| \ / |
|__|__| 


In the above picture, how can you stretch the inner diamond to be the outermost face in the planar layout?

Comment: oops picture is messed. just three concentric squares. With the each corner of each inner square connected to one corner of the next outer square. how can you stretch the inner most square to be the outermost face in the planar layout? How does one do this?

Comment: @Turbo: Select any face $f$. Imagine expanding $f$ in its plane to become larger and larger, distorting the remainder of the polyhedron accordingly.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: The sentence in the second paragraph should say "Second, most of the induction proofs do work for [some] nonconvex polyhedra." Even if you don't use stereographic projection, you still can't put a torus minus a face into the plane, so the same proof *does not work.* You can of course assume that the polyhedron is a sphere, and then the same proof works, but that doesn't show where the proof goes wrong in the non-convex case, which is that the surface minus a disk doesn't fit in the plane.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Thanks, you are right that not every proof works for arbitrary Euler characteristic. I have now made that clear.